# wxPython and Flask integration

Tags: python, flask, wxpython

I am trying to integrate wxPython and Flask into a single application, but I am not sure how to get them to work together as they both want exclusive use of the main thread.

I am calling the application with:

```
export FLASK_APP=keypad_controller
python3 -m flask run -p 2020 -h 0.0.0.0 --eager-loading --no-reload
```

The main code block using Flask is:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    return app
```

I am not sure how to integrate wxPython (below) into the above code, how do I run flask?

```
    wx_app = wx.App()

    main_window = MainWindow(config)
    main_window.Show()

    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Start Flask (`app.run()`) in a separate thread.

Not that if you want `app.run(debug=True)`, you must also pass `use_reloader=False`, because things will go off the rails quickly if Flask decides that it wants needs to reload anything from other than the main thread.